# Ruby on Rails - We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing a tutorial on ruby on rails and am very new to it.  I installed it from http://railsinstaller.org/.  I run the console and have no problem.  I can create dirs and start the server.  I built a new application and then when I go to 127.0.0.1:3000 i get the `"We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)"` error.  I looked in development logs and I see this --

```
ArgumentError (A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb):
```

it goes on much longer but just posting this unless you need to post more.  I'm on Windows 8 Pro with Norton 360 installed.

Comment: have you done as error suggests and placed a >30 character secret token phrase into that config file?

Comment: The file probably already exists. if it doesn't, create `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` and add the linke `YourAppName::Application.config.secret_token = 'some big long random string'` replacing `YourAppName` with the correct application name.

Comment: Hi, Thanks!  I did this and it still doesn't work.  It also tells me this when I start the server:  You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for y
our development environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :lo
g at config/environments/development.rb.....It doesn't make sense because it is already set to log. Thanks Dave.

Comment: Dave B. did you ever solve this? i am also experiencing the same issue